# Git commands for Subversion

Tags: git, svn

I am reading up on Git and have a question.

Can I not use git commands (ex. git clone [remote]) by itself to interact with Subversion?  I understand that I can interact with Subversion by something like git svn ..., but is there a way I can use it without the bridge command?

when I use Git without the bridge command, I am getting an error indicating that the path to the remote repository is not found.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what are you trying to do? can you state examples? are you looking for the equivalent commandos like described here? http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html

Comment: thanks, x29a.  I am just trying to see if I have to use svn bridge command all the time to checkout,checkin,clone,etc... from/to subversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I not use git commands (ex. git clone [remote]) by itself to
>   interact with Subversion?

No. git and Subversion use different communication protocols, and have different underlying concepts. git cannot communicate with a SVN repository without a special bridge like `git svn`.